# Python Zeep - HTTP status 415 (no content available)

Tags: python, web-services, soap, zeep

Hi I am using [zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/) to consume a soap based web service,
and I keep on getting HTTP status 415 error. I dig down a bit and use
Pycharm Debuggger and found that the reason was:

> 'Cannot process the message because the content type \'text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8      XaSOfalw: rtt; ___utmvmBfuwVEwB=yEnqIuCmRhw\' was
>   not the expected type \'text/xml; charset=utf-8\'.'

What is wrong with the content type? and how do I change it in Zeep?

I just created a simple test code which looks like this:

```
from zeep import Client

pretend_wsdl = 'https://pretendwsdl'
client = Client(wsdl=pretend_wsdl)

res = client.service.NameOfService()
print(res)
```

and get this error:

> zeep.exceptions.TransportError: Server returned HTTP status 415 (no
>   content available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using [plugins](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/plugins.html) in zeep client.

My code looks like this:

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep import Plugin


class MyLoggingPlugin(Plugin):

    def ingress(self, envelope, http_headers, operation):
        return envelope, http_headers

    def egress(self, envelope, http_headers, operation, binding_options):
        http_headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8;'
        return envelope, http_headers


pretend_wsdl = 'https://pretendwsdl.com'

client = Client(wsdl=pretend_wsdl, plugins=[MyLoggingPlugin()])

res = client.service.NameOfService()

print(res)
```

I find it weird because the default content type of zeep is text/xml; charset=utf-8;
and the wsdl I'm using doesn't think that the content type from zeep is text/xml; charset=utf-8;

So I used zeep plugins to explicitly set the content type to text/xml; charset=utf-8; and it surprisingly works.